# auto increasing height issue for nested divs

Tags: css, html

I want to increase the size of the outter div when the height of the inner div increases.

height:auto seems to be working only when the contents are added its expanding.. it doesnt seems to be expanding when the inside div height is more.Is there any solution for this in css?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean exactly? Like a JSFiddle of the code you have? Or paste some of your CSS code here which indicates the exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `overflow: hidden` in the parent `div` or otherwise `float` it. Surely you have your inner `div` floated and then parent `div` doesn't consider it to expand its height. If this is the case, both solutions should work.